# rollup MISSING_NODE_BUILTINS error when I include it

Tags: reactjs, rollup, rollupjs

I keep getting this error:

```
src/legacy/widgetlib.tsx → dist/withReact16/browser.js...
{
  code: 'MISSING_NODE_BUILTINS',
  message: "Creating a browser bundle that depends on Node.js built-in module ('punycode'). You might need to include https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-node-builtins",
  modules: [ 'punycode' ],
  toString: [Function]
}
```

I have included rollup-plugin-node-builtins in multiple different ways and I've googled all over the place. Every "solution" I've found seems to basically be the same thing, but it isn't working for me.  I am also not even directly using punycode. Two of my dependencies have it as a dependency.  I am using twitter-text lib and oauth-signature.  If I comment out those two imports I no longer get this problem.  Here is my complete rollup.config.js file:

```js
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image';
import replace from 'rollup-plugin-replace';
import gzipPlugin from 'rollup-plugin-gzip';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import includePaths from 'rollup-plugin-includepaths';
import builtins from 'rollup-plugin-node-builtins';
import globals from 'rollup-plugin-node-globals';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const extensions = ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'];
const { PRODUCTION } = process.env;

const CODES = [
  'THIS_IS_UNDEFINED',
  'MISSING_GLOBAL_NAME',
  'CIRCULAR_DEPENDENCY',
];

const globalVars = {
  react: 'React',
  'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
};

const discardWarning = warning => {
  if (CODES.includes(warning.code)) {
    return;
  }
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.error(warning);
};

const commonConfig = {
  onwarn: discardWarning,
  plugins: [
    replace({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(
        PRODUCTION ? 'production' : 'development'
      ),
    }),
    image(),
    globals(),
    builtins(),
    resolve({
      jsnext: true,
      extensions,
      preferBuiltins: true,
      browser: true,
      mainFields: ['browser', 'jsnext', 'module', 'main'],
    }),
    includePaths({
      paths: ['src'],
      extensions: [...extensions, '.scss', '.json'],
    }),
    commonjs({
      include: 'node_modules/**',
      namedExports: {
        react: Object.keys(React),
        'react-dom': Object.keys(ReactDOM),
      },
    }),
    babel({
      extensions,
      runtimeHelpers: true,
      babelrc: true,
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
    }),
    json(),
    postcss({
      plugins: [],
    }),
    terser(),
  ],
};

const browserLibWithReact16 = {
  ...commonConfig,
  input: 'src/legacy/widgetlib.tsx',
  output: {
    format: 'iife',
    sourcemap: true,
    name: 'WLIB',
    file: 'dist/withReact16/browser.js',
  },
  plugins: [...commonConfig.plugins, gzipPlugin()],
};

const npmWLIBWithReact16 = {
  ...commonConfig,
  input: 'src/widgetlib.tsx',
  output: {
    file: 'dist/withReact16/WLIB.js',
    format: 'esm',
    sourcemap: true,
  },
};

const npmLibNoReact = {
  ...commonConfig,
  external: Object.keys(globalVars),
  input: 'src/widgetlib.tsx',
  output: {
    file: 'dist/index.js',
    format: 'esm',
    sourcemap: true,
  },
};

export default [npmLibNoReact, npmWLIBWithReact16, browserLibWithReact16];
```

The error is only happening for the browserLibWithReact16 config.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I remember correctly when you reuse the same plugins in the commons config its instances get shared among all processes. Define the common config as a function that returns it so they  are not shared among different build processes and try again

Comment: I changed the object to: const getCommonConfig = () => ({ and replaced all occurrences of commonConfig with getCommonConfig().  It still resulted in the same error, though.

Comment: Try this plugin https://github.com/ionic-team/rollup-plugin-node-polyfills and if it doesn't work right away play with plugin order. Your setup looks perfectly fine

Comment: I tried that plugin as well a while back.  I did an npm update on my project and the newer version's error actually suggested that package instead of the builtins I was using. But I still get the same error. :(

Comment: @tkd_aj do u manage to solve the issue? I added rollup-plugin-node-polyfills. But cannot resolve. :(

Comment: No, I'm sorry, this issue was never solved. I ended up commenting out the lines which were being built that used those libs.